# Create original type by adding fields to an Omit type combined with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types

In typescript you can re-create a type with fields removed using `Omit` by adding them:

```
interface Animal {
  name: string
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  goodboy: true
}

const makeDog = (name: string, attributes: Omit<Dog, 'name'>): Dog => ({
  ...attributes,
  name
})
```

However, when you try to do this using a generic type, it fails with an error:

```
// Type 'Omit<T, "name"> & { name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
// 'Omit<T, "name"> & { name: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.
const makeAnimal = <T extends Animal>(name: string, attributes: Omit<T, 'name'>): T => ({
  ...attributes,
  name
})
```

Is there a way to create the `makeAnimal` function?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=3&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChlkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHNCBfQw0SWRFAEQHtGyCAA9IIACY00GbHiIlG-fhIBG-AJ7V6AVwit2CfiDrJsAawgChAXmQAKMhWp0GIRgBpkcMPWCqdSBpqAHlMYDAAHmsvAHInCFiAPgBKamtkGySHBWQAOgKfPwCgj2JScn0WFMNjUwsIdCxcTORIgBVhMQhJaSa5JMdKlz93LyKGEohg5DCIjriE5LTkTqyc8oK8if9A6bKSBNYawiMTMGQYHB0YGA0ARlaG63tYgDFr241Yr3xkJRU6i0yF0KGqpzqFyuNzuACYnnBLP1cNFBIN3p87j8CP9lGpNNooHpkOCgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that it isn't safe in the general case

```
interface Animal {
  name: string
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  goodboy: true
}

interface Cat extends Animal {
  name: 'cat'
}

const makeAnimal = <T extends Animal>(name: string, attributes: Omit<T, 'name'>): T => ({
  ...attributes,
  name
})

// This would make a Cat named 'Mittens', while the interface says a Cat is always named 'cat'
const cat = makeAnimal<Cat>('Mittens', {})
```

You need to explicitly pick from the base type, so that on the call site it can be merged:

```
const makeAnimal = <T extends Animal>(name: string, attributes: Omit<T, 'name'>): Omit<T, 'name'> & Pick<Animal, 'name'> => ({
  ...attributes,
  name
})

// OK
const fluffy: Dog = makeAnimal<Dog>('Fluffy', { goodboy: true })

// valid type error:
// Type 'Omit<Cat, "name"> & Pick<Animal, "name">' is not assignable to type 'Cat'.
// Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"cat"'.
const cat: Cat = makeAnimal<Cat>('Mittens', {})
```

Comment: Very interesting - I had an half-answer for this based on the same thing, but I could explain why `Omit<T, 'name'> & Pick<Animal, 'name'>` worked - very glad to find out!